# Is it possible to see definition of Q_SIGNALS, Q_SLOT, SLOT(), SIGNAL() macros? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Is it possible to see definition of Q_SIGNALS, Q_SLOT, SLOT(), SIGNAL() macros in Qt framework?

P.S. Google gave me nothing in this question.

Comment: You have the Qt headers, all you had to do was search through them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Form `qobjectdefs.h`, for a non-debug compilation:

```
#define Q_SLOTS
#define Q_SIGNALS   protected
#define SLOT(a)     "1"#a
#define SIGNAL(a)   "2"#a
```

The `Q_SLOTS` and `Q_SIGNALS` declarations are only treated specially by the `moc` run, in the final compilation they reduce to simple method declarations. `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` create names from the provided signatures.

Comment: Also, you can look at the output files of moc (in your build directory) to see what it did with the macros.

Answer (score 3):

With visual studio - right click the identifier you're interested in and choose "Go To Definition" or press F12.
If you have Visual Assist, this can also be done with Alt+G when the VS mechanism doesn't work so well.