# Why is slot passed as string? Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
 private:
     Button *createButton(const QString &text, const char *member);
     void abortOperation();
     bool calculate(double rightOperand, const QString &pendingOperator);

Button *pointButton = createButton(tr("."), SLOT(pointClicked()));
```

In qt's calculator example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-calculator.html

The createButton member function takes two constant string. Then why we are passing slots to them as a second argument?

Comment: Because that's what the [`connect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect-3) function expects? It seems that the MOC preprocessor [creates strings](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7771) for metadata like signals and slots, so the `SLOT` macro simply passes along the correct string to identify the slot function.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest summary: The create button function allocates a new button, sets the text, and then connects that button's clicked signal to the slot represented with the string you sent in.

```
     Button *Calculator::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)
     {
         Button *button = new Button(text);

//NOTE right here it uses the string you passed in - BEGIN
         connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);
//NOTE right here it uses the string you passed in - END
         return button;
     }
```

A little bit more detail as to why the signal and slot macros are compatable with strings like this ([per this previous stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881423/1284568)):

> As Neil said, the SLOT and SIGNAL macros are defined as

```
> #define SLOT(a) "1"#a
> #define SIGNAL(a) "2"#a
```

> The #a (with # a stringizing operator) will simply 
>   turn whatever is put within the parentheses into a string
>   literal, to create names from the signatures provided to the macros.
>   The "1" and "2" are merely there to distinguish between slots and
>   signals.
>
> This earlier post should provide you some more insight.
>
> If you wonder about the "why?" of all this macro stuff and
>   preprocessing, I would suggest you read up on the
>   "Meta-Object-Compiler" or MOC. And just for fun you could have a look
>   at what MOC does to the code you provide it with. Look through its
>   output and see what it contains. That should be quite informative.
>
> In short, this preprocessing through MOC allows Qt to implement some
>   features (like the signals and slots) which C++ does not provide as
>   standard. (Although there are arguably some implementations of this
>   concept, not related to Qt, which don't require a Meta Object
>   Compiler)
>
> Hope that helps.

Please note the post I linked has other links of value, that didn't come through with the copy and paste.