# Why does adding a function argument cause a SLOT() to be unrecognised?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a class as follows:

**handler.h:**

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H
#define HANDLER_H

#include <QObject>

class handler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit handler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~handler();

public slots:
    void returnHandler(int input);
};

#endif // HANDLER_H
```

**handler.cpp:**

```
#include "handler.h"
#include "otherclass.h"

handler::handler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

handler::~handler()
{

}

void handler::returnHandler(int input)
{
    otherclass *otherclassPointer = otherclass::getInstance();
    otherclassPointer->returnFunction(input);
}
```

As shown, this is a very simple class, which aims to receive an input and pass the input to a function in an external class ('otherclass'). In my main application ('main.cpp'), I create a `QThread`, and call the `returnHandler` slot when the `QThread` is started, as follows:

**main.cpp:**

```
QThread* newThread = new QThread();
handler* handlerPointer = new handler();
handlerPointer->moveToThread(newThread);
connect(newThread, SIGNAL(started()), handlerPointer, SLOT(returnHandler(someInput)));
newThread->start();
```

The issue I'm having is this:

- I'm currently get the following error:

  > QObject::connect: No such slot handler::returnHandler(someInput) in ../app/main.cpp:100
- However, if I remove the `int input` from the handler class (both the `.h` and `.cpp` files), the `SLOT()` is recognized and called successfully when the `QThread` is started.

Why does adding an argument cause the slot to no longer be recognized?

EDIT: Following some very informative and appreciated comments/answers below, I've modified the approach as follows:

1. Create a signal in the handler class, which matches the parameters of the `returnHandler` slot. E.g. void `handlerSignal`(int).
2. Used the `handlerSignal()` SIGNAL instead of the `QThread::started()` signal in the `connect()`.
3. Emit the `handlerSignal()` once the `QThread` is started.

`

```
QThread* newThread = new QThread();
handler* handlerPointer = new handler();
handlerPointer->moveToThread(newThread);
connect(handlerPointer, SIGNAL(handlerSignal(int)), handlerPointer, SLOT(returnHandler(int)));
newThread->start();
emit handlerPointer->handlerSignal(someInput);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to define connection slot in this way: `SLOT(returnHandler(int)`. I.e. you need to provide rather slot's signature instead.

Comment: Be aware, though, that signatures of `started` and `returnHandler` do not match with the additional parameter...

Comment: You might (if using Qt5) prefer the new syntax: `connect(thread, &QThread::started, hp, &Handler::returnHandler);`. The new syntax even allows usage of a lambda: `connect(thread, &Qthread::started, [&hp, someInput]() { /*...*/ });`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: SIGNAL, SLOT Macro declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880763/qt-signal-slot-macro-declaration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. Qt expects the signal and the slot to have the same parameter types.
2. In SLOT(), you have to provide types, and not names for the parameters.

   ```
   SLOT(returnHandler(int))
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   SLOT(returnHandler(someInput))
   ```

   Qt uses the signals and slots's names and argument list to identify them. I your case, Qt looks for a slot named 'returnHandler' and having only one parameter, from type 'someInput'.

Comment: In this case, the signal would also have to contain an int parameter type, i.e. SIGNAL(started(int))? Is my approach incorrect if I want to pass a variable (of the required type) to the slot function, rather than just the type itself?

Comment: Yes, I think you partly misunderstood the signal - slot mechanism Qt offers.
The parameters your slot will get, are the one provided when invoking the signal that activated the slot.

Comment: Thanks NonoxX, I now understand and have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` takes *strings* as the identification of the signal & slot to connect. The macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` stringise their arguments (using the preprocessor functionality for that). The argument to `SIGNAL` or `SLOT` must therefore be the function name, with parameter *types* in the parentheses. You cannot do argument binding with them.

If you need to connect to a nullary signal, you need a nullary slot.