# Dynamic mapping of all QT signals of one object to one slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect all signals of one QObject to a certain slot.

The slot looks something like this:

```
void SignalIntercepter::signalFired()
{
    std::cout << "Signal is fired!" << std::endl;
}
```

The following code is where the QObject will be passed to:

```
void SignalIntercepter::handleObject(QObject* object)
{
    const QMetaObject *me = object->metaObject();
    int methodCount = me->methodCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++)
    {
        QMetaMethod method = me->method(i);
        if(method.methodType() == QMetaMethod::Signal)
        {
            // How do I connect this signal to the slot?
            // QObject::connect(object, ..., ..., ...);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at

```
const char * QMetaMethod::signature() const
```

then you should be able to use it like

```
QObject::connect(object, method->signature(), this, SLOT(signalFired()));
```

you might need to add `"2"` before the `method->signature()` call because `SIGNAL(a)` makro is defined `SIGNAL(a) "2"#a` as mentioned [Is it possible to see definition of Q_SIGNALS, Q_SLOT, SLOT(), SIGNAL() macros? (Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815172/is-it-possible-to-see-definition-of-q-signals-q-slot-slot-signal-macros)

Comment: Thank you! Without the "2" it gave me some problems. Also in Qt5.4 method.methodSignature() is used instead of signature().
I ended up using 
    QObject::connect(object, "2" + method.methodSignature(), this, SLOT(signalFired()));